# cURL reading an Excel file error

Tags: php, excel, curl

I am trying to execute cURL on a url that is generated using code and stored in a variable. I am having the problem that when I directly pass that variable as url no data is fetched. Where as If I give the value directly in url option using "value" it works fine.
Kindly help me out in this scenario. My code looks as follow

```
$excel_link=$var_lin."9.9.1.5.4";
$response=reader_only($excel_link);
```

and my reader_only() is as following

```
function reader_only($url){

    $feed_ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($feed_ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('text/xml; charset=utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($feed_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($feed_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($feed_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $ch_resp=curl_exec($feed_ch);
    curl_close($feed_ch);
    $ch_resp=set_links($ch_resp);
    return $ch_resp;
}`
```

Comment: Please supply some sample code so we have some idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Edit your question and include this code

Comment: @KevinStich please a kind review of yours is requested

Comment: @Chris okay see it